# ROCR - weird ROC curve

Tags: r, roc

I have some p-values that I use for scoring. Each probability gives a true-positive or false-positive. The idea is to plot the performance of a statistical test. However, the ROC curve that I generate makes no sense. Please copy-and-paste the code to reproduce it.

Code:

```
library(ROCR)
scores <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0.999999999999998,0.999999999999982,0.999999999999943,0.999999999999782,0.999993691351422,0.999930748187179,0.999929270075887,0.995652667490613,0.993101105927916,0.983764828478107,0.962452067884637,0.908463667964783)
labels <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2)
orders <- c(1, 2)

pred <- prediction(scores, labels, label.ordering=orders)
perf <- performance(pred, "tpr","fpr")

plot(perf, colorize=TRUE, cex.lab=2, cex.main=2, lwd=10)
```

[image: enter code here]

Comment: What exactly doesn't make sense?

Comment: @MrFlick Each TP should go vertically up. Each FP should go horizontally by one. The plot shows a diagonal.

Comment: That's description doesn't correspond to what I think of as an ROC curve. A point is plotted for each possible cutpoint for categorization and then a line is drawn between them. You have very few distinct values in `scores`. It doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @MrFlick That might not be the best dataset but that still doesn't explain why the plotting shows a diagonal.

Comment: @Pascal No I didn't. I deleted it.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the diagonal. It's connecting two observations. Would you rather just have points? Essentially you don't have data there so it's just interpolating with a straight line.

Comment: @MrFlick you could write that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**About ROC:**
ROC Curve shows the trade-off between FPR and TPR for all possible threshold values, so that one can look at the curve and pick the best possible threshold value. It entirely depends on the business case you are trying to solve. Do you want to minimize FPR or TPR  or whatever ?

**About the question:**
In this case, the diagonal line implies that there is no trade off between FPR and TPR (till certain point). Cance of mislabeling an observation whether it is a positive or not is the same, which IMO is entirely possible. But is it against intuition ? That depends on the business case you are trying to solve.